# returning HTML in $event->sender->addErrors doesn't work

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, control-panel, error-message

I have a plugin which is checking if there is a duplicate entry before save. I'm trying to give the user back an anchor to the entry which exists so my client can switch without searching for it in a giant structure.

I have this code

```
$event->sender->addErrors([
    'expiryDate' => '<a href='.$entry[0]->cpEditUrl.'>'.$entry[0]->title.'</a>'
]);
```

But somehow I can't render the HTML correctly in the Control Panel, it's getting displayed as plain tekst. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, after digging & debugging a bit further into this issue I found it out myself!

```
$event->sender->addErrors([
    'expiryDate' => Template::raw('<a href='.$entry[0]->cpEditUrl.'>'.$entry[0]->title.'</a>')
]);
```

PS: don't forget to add this to the top of your php file:

```
use craft\helpers\Template;
```